# Getting OWL Classes

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, owl-api

I was writing a module which converts an RDF file to an OWL file and then processes the OWL file which is obtained. I used the OWL API to convert the RDF file to an OWL file as follows :

```
OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology con = man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(filePath+"/OWL/"+fileName));
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("OWL/"+fileName.substring(0,fileName.length()-4)+".owl")) 
{
    man.saveOntology(con, new OWLXMLOntologyFormat(), out);
    out.flush();
}
```

And then I try to read the classes which are present in the OWL file using the Protege API as follows:

```
try {
          OWLModel owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(uri);
          //Getting the named classes present in the OWL File
          Collection classes = owlModel.getUserDefinedOWLNamedClasses();
          for (Iterator it = classes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
          {                           
              DefaultRDFSNamedClass cls = (DefaultRDFSNamedClass) it.next();                                              
              token = cls.getBrowserText();
              System.out.println(token);
          }                                                    
     }
catch (OntologyLoadException ex) 
{
              System.out.println("OWL file processing error");
}
```

This works fine for some OWL files, but for some I get errors such as :

```
SEVERE: An error occurred at parsing the OWL ontology 

@A0_f1d2f23a_ce0f_437a_a0a7_2f00f43f198e

at line 5958 and column 88.
Jena parse error message: {E201} Multiple children of property element -- com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler$1publicId: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl; lineNumber: 5958; columnNumber: 88; {E201} Multiple children of property element
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:199)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:194)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.ParserSupport.warning(ParserSupport.java:214)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.states.Frame.warning(Frame.java:52)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.states.WantLiteralValueOrDescription.startElement(WantLiteralValueOrDescription.java:26)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:137)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:142)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.ARP.load(ARP.java:143)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.ProtegeOWLParser$1.invokeARP(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.ProtegeOWLParser.loadTriples(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.ProtegeOWLParser.run(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.loadKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.loadDomainKB(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.creator.OwlProjectFromUriCreator.create(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(Unknown Source)
```

This happens for example when I process this file :
http://www.w3.org/2004/08/TalkFiles/2005/Talks.rdf

But when I open the converted OWL file using the Protege GUI, it works perfectly fine and I am able to see all the classes. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong. Could someone please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Which version of OWL API and which version of Protégé? The protégé api you're using is based on Jena, which means protégé 3 - last updated a few years ago. There might be bugs that have been fixed since.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Protege 3.5 API. Is there a Java API for Protege 5, because I couldn't find anything on the internet. I am using OWL API 3.5.0 because of some errors I encountered with the later versions.

Comment: Protégé 5 uses owlapi 4.2.5. Which issues did you meet?

Comment: I don't think there are any issues with the OWL API conversion process because when I open the converted OWL file using Protege 5 GUI, I can see the classes. But when I open the OWL file using the Protege 3.5 API in Java or when using the Protege 3.5 GUI, I get the errors mentioned in the question. So, is there an API of Protege 5 for Java or is there any other fix?